# Illegal redeclaration of module which is an IP core in xilinx

Tags: vhdl, verilog, xilinx

I have prepared an IP core named Cache(Block Memory Generator) in Xilinx. When i instantiated it in my module and synthesized it, i got an error saying `Illegal Re-declaration of module<Cache>`. The name of the same cannot be changed since it is an intellectual property of xilinx.

Comment: Have you tried changing the module name to avoid a name conflict?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in your C-code. 
You use a module-name called "`Cache`" that has been used before.

Maybe the module-name is used by xilinx in a standardmodule or by you.
Maybe you are including the "`Cache.h`" file more then one time.

Check your code for lines looking like the following:

```
include "Cache.h"
```

If you find more then one line, try to comment one of the lines out and try to recompile your project.